# How to set client host and port on webpack-hot-client when using server option？

Tags: webpack, websocket, koa

I want to build a full stack koa server, there has some example on webpack-hot-client doc.

Here is my code:

```
const KoaWebpack = require('koa-webpack')
const app = new Koa()
app.use(myApi) // server side code
const server = app.listen(3000)
const webpackMiddleware = KoaWebpack(config, hotClient: { server })
app.use(webpackMiddleware)
```

In browser console, find errors said cannot connect to ws://[::]:3000.

I think it is ref to my server property, but we use nginx as proxy and no need to change that.

So, how can i set currently in this case？

By the way , it is a remote server , not a local server.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to modify server host and port.

I make some mistake.

steps:

1. Make an server side app by koa2 and do not listen on port
2. Set hot client setting to remote server, no need port (random).
3. Use webpack middleware.
4. listen port on what you want

codes:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const koaWebpack = require('koa-webpack');

const devConfig = require('./build/webpack.dev.conf.js');
const app = require('./server');
const { dev, hotClient } = require('./build/config'); //hotClient: { host }

async function devel() {
  const config =  await devConfig;
  await app.ready; // promise => server ready?
  const koaMiddleware = await koaWebpack({ config, hotClient });
  app.use(koaMiddleware);
  app.listen(dev.port, () => console.log(`full stack hot client listen on port ${dev.port}, wait for webpack compile`));
}

devel().catch(console.error);

module.exports = app;
```

I have this question because i cannot listen port currently, it show some process already use it.
This situation occurred to me that's terminal been close but nodemon not.
A lots of nodemon "work well" when i change file, so i cant use port what i want.
That let me judge the error and wast so many time on webpack and koa port problem.